# How can i get/use accessToken in AuthInterceptor class in Angular 8

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

How can i get/use accessToken in AuthInterceptor class & adding it to every API (.NetCore) call.
 I've already implemented

```
 getAccessToken() {
    return Auth.currentSession().then(res => {
      return res.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
    });
  }
```

in authService, But i can't seem to use this in intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler){} method. Any way around or flow changes i can implement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, convert your promise to an `Observable` into your `AuthService.ts` :

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

getAccessToken(): Observable<string> {
  return from(Auth.currentSession()).pipe(
    switchMap(session => from(session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken())
  )
};
```

Then you can use it easily into your `AuthHttpInterceptor` :

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.authService.getAccessToken().pipe(
      switchMap(jwtToken => {
        // clone the request to add the new header.
        const authReq = req.clone({ 
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`) 
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `of(session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()); ` in service file else it will return array of chars instead of whole string as  a token.