# Angular 9 http Interceptor get Aws accesstoken

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, aws-amplify, rxjs6

I am following this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611949/how-can-i-get-use-accesstoken-in-authinterceptor-class-in-angular-8) to add AWS access token in angular HTTP interceptor, But the code is going in an infinite loop and I am getting `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` error.

The console.log of token value showing single characters.

Thank you in advance

Here is the code

service.ts

```
 getAccessToken(): Observable<string> {
    return from(Auth.currentSession()).pipe(
      switchMap(session => from(session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()))
    );
  }
```

interceptor.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from 'app/user.service';

import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public userService: UserService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.userService.getAccessToken().pipe(
      switchMap(jwtToken => {
        console.log(jwtToken);
        // clone the request to add the new header.
        req = req.clone({
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`),
        });
        if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
          req = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
          });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good practice to have an using http request in interceptor.. Instead, you can pull "jwtToken" once at the application opening and import it into localStarege.

**in app.module.ts**

```
import {UserService} from './UserService';

export function appInitializerFn(userService: UserService) {
  return (): Promise<boolean> => userService.getJwtToken()
}

...

@NgModule({
 providers : [UserService, {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [UserService]
    },] )
```

**in UserService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
   

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getJwtToken(): Promise<any> { 
    return this.http
      .get('get/toke/url'))
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", data); 
      }).catch((err: Error) => {  
      }).finally(() => {
        console.info(' token init ');
        return Promise.resolve(true)
      })
  } 
}
```

```
intercept(
   req: HttpRequest<any>,
   next: HttpHandler
 ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   const jwtToken: string = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

   req = req.clone({
         headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`),
       });
       if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
         req = req.clone({
           headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
         });
       }
       return next.handle(req);
   );
```